# Some topbar items aren't properly 'selected' when using the Tab key to navigate

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, accessibility, tab-key

When using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to navigate the top bar, most items have a vertical line to the left and to the right when they are selected. Except for the profile link and the Stack Exchange 'hamburger' menu; see the first and last screenshot below. They only have a vertical line on one side, which makes it harder to see they're selected:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

(tested in Firefox and Chrome on macOS)

Comment: I've found those vertical lines to be specific to Firefox and the same problem happens with several other elements. I can't explain it but from experience I guess those are elements with zero distance between them, sometimes the browser will make those very narrow lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point, the highlighting (shown when <kbd>Tab</kbd>'ing) on each of those elements was changed. The entire element is highlighted, instead of two vertical lines on either side of the top bar element.

Here's a GIF showing the current highlight on each of the top bar elements (on the right) when using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key:

[image]

Tested on Chrome (latest version) on Windows 11.